# Grab all blank lines by Antlr 4 lexer/parser

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Trying to grab all blank lines (only line numbers) by Antlr 4 lexer/parser for a given PHP file. The grammar I am using is available on GitHub [Antlr grammar for PHP](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/php).

The Whitespace token defined as:

```
Whitespace:         [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

I changed this to:

```
Whitespace: (
             ' ' 
             | '\t' 
             | '\r' '\n' { newline(); } 
             | '\n'       { newline(); }
            );
```

But it's collecting almost all the lines, since every line is ending by "**\n**". Any expert advice can give me a lead.

The sample PHP to test:

```html
<?php

//02-5002201-00001 5002201 - Machine hours test

 function test()
 { 
/* Name:   Test.php

 Title:   Demo

 by:    XYZ
*/
  if (true && false)
  {  
   echo "aa";
  }

//TODO  
  echo <<<SEGDTA
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui.css"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="min.js"></script>
  SEGDTA;
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this instead:

```antlr
lexer grammar DemoLexer;

EmptyLine
 : {super.getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? [ \t]* '\r'? '\n'
 ;

Whitespace
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;

Other
 : .
 ;
```

If I run the following test class:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String source = "foo\n" +
                "\n" +
                "bar\n" +
                "    \n" +
                "   baz   \r\n" +
                " \t\t\n" +
                "\tend\n\n";

        DemoLexer lexer = new DemoLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));

        for (Token t : lexer.getAllTokens()) {

            String name = lexer.getTokenNames()[t.getType()];
            String text = t.getText().replace("\r","\\r").replace("\n","\\n").replace("\t","\\t");

            System.out.printf("%-20s '%s'\n", name, text);
        }
    }
}
```

this will be printed:

```
Other                'f'
Other                'o'
Other                'o'
EmptyLine            '\n'
Other                'b'
Other                'a'
Other                'r'
EmptyLine            '    \n'
Other                'b'
Other                'a'
Other                'z'
EmptyLine            ' \t\t\n'
Other                'e'
Other                'n'
Other                'd'
EmptyLine            '\n'
```

See: http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenSource.html#getCharPositionInLine()

Comment: this approach is not working...The **EmptyLine** lexer rule never getting a chance to match and trigger

Comment: After removing the **+** sign from **Whitespace** rule, the *EmptyLine* getting triggered, but after every empty line match, error being generated
<h2>
line 3:0 extraneous input '\r\n' expecting {<EOF>, HtmlText, HtmlScriptOpen, HtmlStyleOpen, HtmlDtd, HtmlOpen, HtmlClose, '/>', HtmlSlash, HtmlEquals, HtmlStartQuoteString, HtmlStartDoubleQuoteString, HtmlHex, HtmlDecimal, HtmlName, HtmlEndQuoteString, HtmlQuoteString, HtmlEndDoubleQuoteString, HtmlDo.....}

Comment: If you're all of a sudden not `skip`ping white space characters (or line breaks) in your grammar, then your parser will indeed be complaining about the token stream not being that what it expects to be. This is a whole different question. Your question here is how to make a distinction between empty lines and space characters, which I think I answered. If you have other issues, I recommend you create a new question and provide enough information (your exact grammar) for others to be able to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146654/discussion-between-kishore-and-bart-kiers).

Comment: There is nothing to discuss :) My previous comment is sufficient for this Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the only processing you do with the PHP code? If so you could simply load the file line by line and count empty entries. No parser needed in such a case.

**Update**

Since you have that parser anyway you could use the token stream and walk over all tokens. Whenever you see a linebreak check the previous token and if that is also a line break (or this is the first token in the stream) you found an empty line. You can even keep your whitespace hidden, since the token stream will give you all tokens on all channels (unless you filtered it).

Counting empty lines is a semantic step anyway and the parser (which is doing the syntactic step) is not the right place for this.

**Update 2**

Here's code that should work (based on your attempt):

```
CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(new AntlrPHPLexer(charStream));

tokenStream.fill(); // Load all tokens.
int counter = 0;
List<Token> tokens = tokenStream.getTokens();
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i) {
  if (tokens.get(i).getType() == AntlrPHPLexer.Linebreak) {
    if (i == 0 || (tokens.get(i - 1).getType() == AntlrPHPLexer.Linebreak))
      ++counter;
  }
}
```

You have to split your whitespaces into 2 rules:

```
Whitespace: ([ \t]+ | Linebreak) -> skip;
Linebreak: [\r\n];
```

Note that I did not use a loop for the `Linebreak` call in `Whitespace`, by intention.

Comment: No. I am doing lots of thing by lexer/parser..like printing only multi-line/single-line comments, counting of some specific words etc.

But the only thing to get all empty lines is still pending!!!

Comment: Tried this code, but **Whitespace** not getting received as a Token in while loop<br/>
<br/>
`CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(new AntlrPHPLexer(charStream));
Token prevToken , currToken = null;
while (tokens.LA(1) != IntStream.EOF)
{
 currToken = tokens.LT(1);
 tokens.consume();

 if (prevToken != null && currToken.getText().trim().equals("\n") && "\n".equals(prevToken.getText()))
  ++counter;

 prevToken = currToken;
}`
<br/>

Comment: Sorry to say..its not working again...even the Linebreak not printing any thing
`
Linebreak: '\r'? '\n'
 {
  System.out.println("Linebreak: " + getLine()); 
 };`